# Regarding Arraylists

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an two arraylists each containing products
ArrayList productList1;
ArrayList prroductList2;
each product has various attributes(eg id, name, price)
I want to compare the products of these two arraylists with respect to the product id and return the product which is not similar

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: How do you get the attributes? What are the lists composed of? Single id value or more complex maps?

Comment: You can use for loop for comparison, inside which you need to compare productList1[i] with productList2[0...n] sequentially and upon false condition just put the odd one in another ArrayList or HashMap. Sole criteria is what definition you give to the comparison of elements of two arraylists i.e. main.

Answer (score 2):

You must Override `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods in `Product` class and than you can use `list.removeAll(Collection<?> c)` to remove elements from lits that are contained in another.